# Is it possible to pay gas fee for transaction from contract?

Tags: contract-development

I have created function for consumer to deposited balance into contract, My goal is to deduct gas fee for purchasing subscription from his/her deposited balance as same as subscription is deducting from his/her balance,is it possible ?